# Creating JSON return "strings" from a webservice for use with jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, json

I tried implementing a simple web service into an asp.net application using the tutorial found here: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/JSON-EnabledWCFServicesInASPNET35.aspx#1301 and http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx

The problem is, my data is being returned as seen in this screen shot (according to firebug):
[image]

```
    $("#btnGet").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "TimeService.svc/GetCar",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

My Web Service method looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
public string GetCar()
{
    using (var sqlc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CarTracker.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"))
    {
        sqlc.Open();
        var cmd = sqlc.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CarID, CarName FROM tblCars";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            string sCar = "";
            int testcount = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < testcount; i++)
            {
                reader.Read();
                sCar += reader["CarName"].ToString();
            }


            return sCar; // Car_1
        }
    }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Where does the 'd' in firebug come
   from?
2. How do I build 'JSON-style'
   "strings" based on my db to return
   back to the jquery ajax function?

Ideally I would wantthe jquery ajax data to look something like this:

```
{"TotalCars": x, "CarList":[{"CarName":"x1", "CarID":"id1"},{"CarName":"x2", "CarID":"id2"}]}
```

So then with jquery I can do things like `alert(data.TotalCars);` and all that sort of stuff.

Please bear in mind that I'm -very- new to this so I appreciate any help you can provide.
Thank you in advance! <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "d" is used by the webservice framework to ensure that a naked array is never returned by a service. This is done to work around a potential [cross-site Javascript exploit](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx).

You want to create classes that describe your data contract, for example:

```
[DataContract]
public class CarCollection {
    [DataMember]
    public int TotalCars { get { return CarList.Count; }}
    [DataMember]
    public List<Car> CarList { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Car {
    [DataMember]
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CarId { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would build up your return value using those classes. You can also tell WCF to accept the HTTP GET method and JSON serialization for the response with the `WebGet` attribute:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string GetCar()
{
    // You will probably build this up from your databas
    var cars = new CarCollection { CarList = new List<Car>() {
        new Car { CarName = "x1", CarId = "id1" },
        new Car { CarName = "x2", CarId = "id2" },
        new Car { CarName = "x3", CarId = "id3" },
    }};

    return cars;
}
```

WCF will automatically serialize your object graph into JSON and send it back to the client.

You can also then use the simplified JQuery method [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$("#btnGet").click(function () {
    $.get("TimeService.svc/GetCar", function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually the "d" is added to prevent the javascript from being evaluated in order to mitigate against a crosssite scripting attack. Details can be found here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx

Comment: This worked! But... I had a few more issues. 
 
When using : [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] firebug gives me "405 Method Not Allowed".

Comment: Thanks for the info on the "d". I actually still need to reference it in the jquery part:

                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d.CarName);
                } but i need to remove the WebGet

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the pointer, now that you mention it I think I remember reading that post a long time ago. Seems stupid though that the framework does this since it doesn't work in any browser except Firefox <= 2. Doesn't even work with IE6, arguably one of the most exploited browsers of all time...

Comment: @Robodude sorry, you may not be using the WCF HTTP programming model (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412172.aspx); if that's the case then WebGet will not work for you.

Comment: @JoshPerry, will this work with just a website with web service or must I it be WCF? Also, If I have linq query today against a stored procedure how will this fit in? I'm going to post the question.

Answer (score 2):

1) The 'd' in the JSON response is put in by ASP.Net to prevent the service from returning a valid javascript statement so that it cannot be parsed and instantiated as a new object in javascript to prevent cross-site scripting attacks.

2) The webservice will automatically turn your .Net objects into JSON if you annotate the web method with `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true, ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]`.  Using the CarCollection by @joshperry, try:

```
[WebMethod()]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true, ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
public CarCollection GetCars()
{
    CarCollection carResult = new CarCollection();
    ...
    return carResult;
}
```